# Pyramid: restart the apps in a exception view

Tags: python, apache, pyramid, waitress

The command that I've been using is:

```
 pserve development.ini --reload
```

and every time when i meet a error like SQLAlchemy's "IntegrityError" or something else,
I have to kill pserve an type the command again to restart the apps.

Is there a method i can restart the apps in a exception view like this?

```
@view_config(context=Exception)
def error_view(exc, request):
    #restart the waitress or apache...
    return Response("Sorry there was an error, wait seconds, we will fix it soon.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Restarting your server is not a sensical response to an `IntegrityError`. This is something that is expected to happen and you need to handle it. Restarting the server really makes no sense in the context of anything other than development.

If you run into exceptions in development, fix the code and save the file and the `--reload` will automatically restart your server for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to restart the application after an exception (supposedly because nothing works after an exception otherwise) it suggests your requests try to re-use the same transaction - in other words, your application is not configured properly.

You should be using a session configured with ZopeTransactionExtension as Pyramide's scaffolds generate.

If you show us some code we may be able to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.